# Netlogo how to remove one turtle if it touches another one

Tags: netlogo

We are working on a netlogo model in which fishes are hunted and eaten by shark. It is built on the flocking 3d - alternate model.

At the moment we have the sharks able to follow the fishes, but we can't figure out how to make them eat them. Right now the fishes die when they touch each other:

```
ask fishes
  [ flock
    ;; if we've hit something
    ;; we're a goner
    if pcolor != black   [ hatch-dead-fishes 1
      [ bk 1 ]
      die ]
  ]
```

What we want is something like:

```
ask fishes
  [ flock
    if xcor and ycor and zcor of shark == xyz cor of a fish   
      [ hatch-dead-fishes 1
      [ bk 1 ]
      die ]
  ]
```

Now clearly we don't know how to properly write this code. We also noticed that when a fish dies it doesn't actually get removed from the screen. Anyone know

Any help would be welcome! Thanks :)

Comment: coordinates are numbers with lots of decimal places, so they are never going to match. King-Ink's answer answers your specific question and will make the sharks eat fishes on the same patch, but you might like to do something with the `distance` or `in-radius` function to capture fish within a certain distance of the shark

Answer (score 3):

Your fish are most likely disappearing they are just being replaced by hatch-dead-fish.

to have the sharks eat the fish I have found that

```
ask sharks [ask fish-here [die]]
```

(assuming fish and sharks are two breeds if they are not you should make them two breeds)

changing your code to do about the same thing is much longer

```
ask fishes
[ flock
if pxcor = [pxcor] of shark and pycor = [pycor] of shark and pzcor = [pzcor] of          shark 
    [ hatch-dead-fishes 1
    [ bk 1 ]
  die ]
]
```

I took the liberty of changing the coordinates to patch rather than turtles because it is really hard to get a collision on floating-points

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! We just added the code, but now it seems the sharks are not eating any fish. This might have to do with the rest of our code though.. Would you take a quick look at our code for us? :)